# Foreach loop with two arrays and if-condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this array (part of) from an extern API source:

```
[wow_accounts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4426107
                    [characters] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                    [name] => Name1
                                    [id] => 48889376
                                    [realm] => Array
                                        (
                                            [key] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [href] => https:/XX
                                                )

                                            [name] => Malygos
                                            [id] => 1098
                                            [slug] => malygos
                                        )

                                )
```

I have also this mysql table.

[image: mysql table]

I have two arrays and a "if condition" inside a foreach loop but I don´t get an output. The mysql connection is up. Probably there is a mistake in the foreach loop or if condition.

**I tried the following:**

```
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM mysqltable");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $names[] = $row['firstname'];
        }

$data2 = //Link tothe APi

        echo '<table class="formatHTML5" id="myTable">';

        foreach($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $key => $item && $names as $name) {

            if($name["firstname"] == $item['name'] && $name["lastname"] == $item['realm']['name']  ) {
                $class_string = '';
            } else {
                $class_string = ' class="my-additional-class"';
            }

            echo '<tr'.$class_string.'>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo  $item['name'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo  $item['realm']['name'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo  '<button class="btnSelect">Select</button>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `&& $names as $name` is also not valid in the `foreach()` specification.

Comment: And even if any of this worked, why would you expect the rows returned from the query to be in the same order as the elements of the `characters` array?

Comment: I corrected the variable before ['wow_accounts'].  $item['realm']['name'] and $name['lastname'] are both the endpoit of the arrays. Why can´t they be equal? I think here is the mistake.

Comment: What are you really trying to do with the `if` condition? Are you trying to check if the character from the API result is in the table, or trying to check if the row from the table is in the API result? They won't be in 1-to-1 correspondence, so looping through the arrays in parallel won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't scroll right, I just saw `$item['realm']`, not `$item['realm']['name']`.

Comment: You're only putting `$row['firstname']` in the `$names` array. It's not a 2-dimensional array, so you can't use `$name['firstname']` and `$name['lastname']`

Comment: Exactly I try to check if the characters from the API are in my mysql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested loops to check if the characters from the API are in the table. You have to loop through the entire `$names` array to tell if the name is in the table.

You also need to put both `firstname` and `lastname` in the `$names` array, not just `firstname`. Just put the whole `$row` in the array.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mysqltable");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $names[] = $row;
}
//...
foreach($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $character) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        if ($character['name'] == $name['firstname'] && $character['realm']['name'] == $name['lastname']) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    $class_string = $found ?  '' : ' class="my-additional-class"';
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to showing all errors add this under the `<?php` tag

```
<?php
    `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);` 


$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM mysqltable");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $names[] = $row['firstname'];
}

$data2 = "";//Link tothe APi

echo '<table class="formatHTML5" id="myTable">';

foreach ($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $key => $item) {

    if ($names["firstname"] === $item['name'] && $names["lastname"] === $item['realm']['name']) {
         $class_string = '';
    } else {
        $class_string = ' class="my-additional-class"';
    }

    echo '<tr' . $class_string . '>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $item['name'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $item['realm']['name'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<button class="btnSelect">Select</button>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
 echo '</table>';



}
```

Comment: The script has syntax errors, so none of the code will run, so these statements will never be executed.

Comment: oh yeah the `foreach($data2['wow_accounts']['0']['characters'] as $key => $item && $names as $name)`

Comment: `$names` is not an associative array.

Comment: try soming like this `<?php
foreach ($data as $key => $vale){
    if (is_array($key)){
        foreach ($key as $j => $v ){
            // code hre 
        }
    }
}`